# Mangled UV unwrapp

Tags: texturing, uv, faces, uv-image-editor

Sometimes I get a strange unwrap where one face is unwrapped the wrong way.

[image: mirrored UV face]

As you can see in the picture when I baked the AO map, one face is flipped along the X axis. I have checked:

- All normals are pointing in the right direction.
- There are no double vertices (all vertices connected in model).
- All seams are marked correctly.

In the UV map this troublesome face is not connected right with its neighbour vertices.

I have tried all the unwrap methods but none of them fixes this. I have also tried to mark the seams in different ways but no changes. This face is always mirrored in the X direction.

Is this a common problem that has a simple solution? Any ideas of how to fix this so the unwrap works?

Comment: Just to be sure - select one vert and Ctrl L to Select Linked. It should select everything if the mesh is actually all connected. Also try Shift Ctrl Alt M to Select Non-Manifold. This may reveal geometry problems if there are any.

Comment: Did you try to save the texture and reload it?

Comment: If what I suggested doesn't work, [upload the .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for us to examine.

Comment: I deleted the face and added it back again, then it solved itself.